# Issue with Javascript this context

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with following code.`console.log` is working fine in `logName` method but not giving desired output in `logNameAgain` method. I tried to google but in vain. Could someone please explain what is going on here?

```
var testObj = {
    name: "This is test object",
    logName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);  //Works fine 

        function logNameAgain() {
            console.log(this.name); //Not giving expected result;
        }

        logNameAgain();

    }
};

testObj.logName();
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tc096d6/)**

Seems like `console.log` in `logNameAgain` method pointing to `window`. It doesn't really make any sense to me?

Update: I understand that this can be fixed by using bind/call or self but I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Hint: you are not passing `this` in any way to the call. Either qualify the call with an object or bind this with `bind`.

Comment: In response to your update, the duplicate I linked to begins with an explanation of why this is happening, in the very first section entitled "What you should know about `this`". If you are interested in further explanation, please give more information about what you don't understand about that explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.bind()` (see the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuspyzp8/)):

```
var testObj = {
    name: "This is test object",
    logName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);

        var logNameAgain = function() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }.bind(this);

        logNameAgain();

    }
};

testObj.logName();
```

The problem was that the new function inside of `logName` has the `window` (global) context. All that means is that you need to somehow pass in the local context. `Function.prototype.bind` does just that.

If browser support is a concern, you can also do this hacky thing:

```
var testObj = {
    name: "This is test object",
    logName: function() {
        var that = this;
        console.log(this.name);

        var logNameAgain = function() {
            console.log(that.name);
        };

        logNameAgain();

    }
};

testObj.logName();
```

That's only if you need to support IE8 and below. Here's the compat table for `.bind()` (courtesy of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

[image: bind]